# How does one detect when the wallpaper has changed (Windows XP or greater)?

Tags: windows, windows-7, wallpaper, desktop-wallpaper

I have figured out how to change the desktop wallpaper (there are dozens of examples on the Internet.)

One thing that still eludes me: how do I detect when the wallpaper has changed? (Say via the Display control panel or another program changing it.)

Comment: What programming language/environment? .Net? MFC? Win32?

Answer (score 8):

Add a message handler for WM_SETTINGCHANGE, SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged in .NET.  Check if the wallpaper is still the same.

Comment: It's `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`, but yes, I would say that this is a good way to be notified.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example in C# to retrieve the wallpaper. All you would need to add is some additional code to store the last wallpaper and check to see if it is different.

```
RegistryKey wallpaper = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop",false);
string wallpapername = wallpaper.GetValue("wallpaper").ToString();          
wallpaper.Close();
```

If you were writing something in a non .net language you could use the Win32 API `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` function to check to see if this value has changed:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper
```