# How to check if Windows wallpaper changed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can we get notified by Windows when the user has changed their Desktop Background/Wallpaper? I'm looking for some kind of event, and I'd rather not use a Timer and keep checking all the time.

Comment: Use the SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged event instead of the timer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect wallpaper changing as a result of the Windows 7 slideshow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537836/how-can-i-detect-wallpaper-changing-as-a-result-of-the-windows-7-slideshow)

Comment: @David, I did see that question but dismissed it as I thought it was only for wallpapers part of slideshows. But thanks, I'll look at it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a message handler for **[WM_SETTINGCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**, **[SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx)** in .NET

> In all operating systems since at least Windows 95 a WM_SETTINGCHANGE
>   was sent when the desktop wallpaper has been changed by the user or a
>   slideshow.

Source [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014542/how-does-one-detect-when-the-wallpaper-has-changed-windows-xp-or-greater)

Comment: Oh my. I wasn't expecting this to be doable this easily. Thank you very much, Sir.